# PHP não reconhece conexão como parâmetro

Tags: php, pdo, mvc, connectionstring

Estou fazendo um sistema usando o MVC (primeira vez que utilizo ele no PHP), e quando vou fazer o login aparece:

> Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Login::login(), 2 passed in C:\wamp64\www\php_pdo\controller\logincontroller.php on line 19 and exactly 3 expected in C:\wamp64\www\php_pdo\model\login.php
>
> Too few arguments to function Login::login(), 2 passed in C:\wamp64\www\php_pdo\controller\logincontroller.php on line 19 and exactly 3 expected in C:\wamp64\www\php_pdo\model\login.php on line 29

No caso o erro diz que está faltando um parâmetro, eu testei o `post` do login, e está indo os 2 valores (senha e usuário), e `conexãO` está indo também, porém ele ainda apresenta esses erros..

Códigos:

View: sign-in.php:

```
    <form method="post" action="" >
        <input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Digite seu nome de usuário"><br>
        <input type="password" name="senha" placeholder="Digite sua senha"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="btn" value="Entrar"><br>
    </form>   
    
    <?php
    // caso haja post, esse if será executado
    if($_POST){
        // Aqui ele vai filtar o post, o ultimo parametro serve para tirar tags e caracteres especiais.
        $usuario = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'usuario', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $senha = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'senha', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        // aqui ele inclui a classe
        require_once '../controller/logincontroller.php';
        // aqui ele chama o método Login, por ser static não precisa criar um objeto.
        LoginController::logar($usuario, $senha);
        
    }
```

Controller logincontroller.php:

```
require_once '../model/login.php';

class LoginController {

 static function logar($usuario, $senha){
    $result = Login::login($usuario, $senha);
    if ($result){
        echo '<script> confirm("Bem vindo ao sistema!");
                       window.location("menu"); <script>';
            // header("Location: menu");
    } else {
        echo '<script> confirm("Senha ou usuário incorreto!");
                       window.location("sign-in"); <script>';
    }
 }

}
```

Model login.php:

```
require_once '../projeto/connectionfactory.php';

class Login {

private $usuario;
private $senha;
private $con;

function __construct($usuario, $senha) {
    $this->usuario = $usuario;
    $this->senha = $senha;
    $this->con = ConnectionFactory::getConnection();
}

static function login($usuario, $senha, $con) {
    // isso é para tratar erros
    try {
        // aqui cria a transação, tudo que for feito dentro, fica protegido
        $con->beginTransaction();
        // puxar senha
        $stmt = $con->prepare("select senha from tbl_login where usuario = :usuario");
        $stmt->bindParam('usuario', $usuario);
        $stmt->execute();
        $hash = null;
        while ($obj = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $hash = $obj['senha'];
        }
        if (password_verify($senha, $hash)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
}
```

Projeto connectionfactory.php:

```
class ConnectionFactory{
static function getConnection(){
    $db = 'tec_find';
    $user = 'root';
    $psw = '';
    try {
        $con = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$db", $user, $psw); 
        $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        return $con;
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
    }   
}
static function testarConnection(){
    if(ConnectionFactory::getConnection()){
        // entra sempre aqui
        echo 'Conectado';
    } else { 
        echo 'Conectado';
    }
    
}
}
```

estrutura de pasta:

[image: Estrutura]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leandro boa noite.

Você você criou uma classe com um __construct e um método estático, e nesse __contruct você passou a sua conexão, mas tem um problema, quando usamos o método estatico não instanciamos a classe, assim o __construct fica sem razão por existir ali.

Se quiser continuar fazendo dessa maneira, tente assim.

```
require_once '../projeto/connectionfactory.php';

class Login {

private $usuario;
private $senha;

public function __construct($usuario, $senha) {
    $this->usuario = $usuario;
    $this->senha = $senha;
}

public static function login($usuario, $senha) {
     $con = ConnectionFactory::getConnection();
    // isso é para tratar erros
    try {
        // aqui cria a transação, tudo que for feito dentro, fica protegido
        $con->beginTransaction();
        // puxar senha
        $stmt = $con->prepare("select senha from tbl_login where usuario = :usuario");
        $stmt->bindParam('usuario', $usuario);
        $stmt->execute();
        $hash = null;
        while ($obj = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $hash = $obj['senha'];
        }
        if (password_verify($senha, $hash)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, nem tinha reparado nisso.

Answer (score 0):

@Leandro, na verdade está acusando que apenas 2 argumentos foram passados e o esperado são 3, você está chamando a função `Login::login` assim:

```
$result = Login::login($usuario, $senha);
```

Mas ela está definida assim:

```
static function login($usuario, $senha, $con) {
```

Tenta assim:

```
$result = Login::login($usuario, $senha, $this->con);
```

Comment: Cotinuou com o mesmo erro :/

Comment: Se eu tirar a $con do parâmetro, e dentro do método de `Login` colocar $this->con->, ele ainda apresenta o mesmo erro.